# Can set of complex numbers be a subring of the ring of quaternions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was studying an algebra book by Dummit and Foote, there I saw an example of subrings; $\mathbb H_{\mathbb Z}=$ $\{a+bi+cj+dk: a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$=$\{a+bi+cj+dk:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R\}$. So I was thinking if $\mathbb C=\{a+bi+0j+0k:a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ can be a subring of ring of quaternion $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$.

First I checked that this is the subset of $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$ which it is and it's also a ring in itself but I am having doubts about it. As we can see that the ring $\mathbb C$ is a commutative ring (in fact, a field), and $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$ is a noncommutative ring. So is this possible that a subring is commutative and the ring is not? Or I am getting everything incorrectly?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: "So is this possible that a ring is commutative and the subring is not?" I think you mean it the other way around. A subring is commutative and the ring is not. Because that's what your quaternions-complex example claims to illustrate.

Comment: oh yeah.. I am so sorry.. I will correct this.. thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the ring $\Bbb H$ is not commutative, but the subring $\Bbb C$ is commutative. This is no contradiction. The *other way around* is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! So $\mathbb C$ is a subring of $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Please at least give the reason for the downvote.. I made effort and I wanted to be sure of my answer, maybe it was too basic but nobody becomes a master in one day. should you people not support the newcomers? Or at least give the reason for downvoting the question?

Comment: A hint for newcomers.  Ignore a small number of downvotes.

Comment: @MansiTyagi: Yes, $\mathbb C$ is a subring of $\mathbb H_{\mathbb R}$, as it is a subset, and it is a ring under the restricted addition and multiplication operations. I'm sorry to see that your question has been downvoted, as it does meet the standards of the site.

Comment: Thank you!! I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible for a noncommutative ring to have a commutative subring. In fact, *every* noncommutative ring has at least one commutative subring, namely the trivial ring.*

What is impossible is for a commutative ring to have a noncommutative subring: if $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in R$, then the same must be true for any subset of $R$.

---

*The definitions of ring and subring vary from author to author. While what I said is true for the definitions given in Dummit and Foote, other sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring#Properties)) disagree.

Comment: If we require rings to be unital, then every ring still has a commutative subring: the canonical image of $\mathbb{Z}$ (which is the initial object in the category of unital rings), that is, the subring generated by the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe! my doubts are all clear now.

Comment: No problem @MansiTyagi! I'm glad I could help.